# sidr menu scroll is working fine in desktop but dont on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, sidr

Im following the sidr documentation because Im trying to do a slider responsive menu.

Im importing the light css that the creator of this provided:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.sidr.light.css" type="text/css" />
```

And then I have my html, and the script to initialize the plugin.

And its working fine on destktop when I click in the link to open the menu the menu opens with my menu and submenu items, and with a scroll vertical bar because I have a menu with many items.

But on mobile, the scroll its not working, I have a horizontal bar and not vertical and when I scroll my menu dont goes down, I only move my other html content.

Somebody thery already tried to use this script and now how I can solve this situation?

This is my jQuery to start the script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#simple-menu').sidr({
       name: 'sidr', 
      speed: 200, 
      side: 'left',
      source: null, 
      renaming: true, 
      body: 'body'

     });
});
```

Comment: Try using -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; on the Parent Element of the Slider.

Comment: Thank you very much SSS, it worked just fine :)!! If you want give the answer so I can accept it!